# How to run .html File from WebStorm

Tags: dojo, webstorm

We do unit tests via .html files so that we can interact in a web form also.  We also just run the dojo test runner.

I have been able to run the .hml file from Aptana but when I try webstorm for the first time, never tried it, love this IDE, I see that when in my .html file the run button at the top is disabled.

So how do I run an .html file that's got markup and javascript from WebStorm and have it come back and hit my debug points inside Webstorm?  Does webstorm scrape in what you see in FireFox also or do you have to keep toggling back and fourth such as when you step to the next debug point, tab back to the browser to see the results...or is there a nice way in webstorm to see the markup in runtime at the same time?

All in all I am just trying to get this .html file to run that's got javascript in it and some Dojo runner, etc. in it since I'm using Dojo in this .html file.

Comment: Did you check [these](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_JavaScript_locally_in_Firefox_with_WebStorm_and_PhpStorm) [documents](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Remote_JavaScript_debugging_with_WebStorm_and_PHPStorm)? If you are using Chrome, [Live Edit](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/08/liveedit-plugin-features-in-detail/) can also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Either just open it manually or allow debug from localhost port.

So appearnetly it's not obvious to open a file in WebStorm there is a row of icons that appear in the top right corner of the text editor pane.
You have to hold SHIFT down when clicking the supported/installed browsers icons hidden there, or it will open in the deployment's location (via FTP server settings etc).

Try ALT-F2 for Preview file in... from "View" menu.